# Is there support for routing on delete in repository or query annotation?

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to get working deletion of one document in spring data elasticsearch repository. And can't find way how to solve this error:

> [userindex] RoutingMissingException[routing is required for
>   [userindex]/[address]/[12]

I have two linked documents:

```
@Document(indexName = "userindex", type = "user")
public class User {

  @Field(index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed, type = FieldType.Long)
  private Long userId;
  ...
}

@Document(indexName = "userindex", type = "address")
public class Address {

  @Field(type = FieldType.String)
  private String name;

  @Field(index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed, type = FieldType.String)
  private String addressId;

  @Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
  @Parent(type = "user")
  private String parentId;
  ...
}
```

When I'm trying to delete one address via ElasticsearchCrudRepository<Address, Long> by using standard method delete(Long id) I receiving RoutingMissingException mentioned above.

If I'm trying to do it using ElasticSeach client, like this:

```
  client.prepareDelete().setIndex("userindex")
    .setType("address")
    .setParent("user")
    .setId(id.toString())
  .execute().get();
```

everything works fine, but seems to me working directly with client is not the spring-data way.

Also I can't find any way how to customize delete method with annotation *org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Query*.
I checked sources of *org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate* and can't find any way how to add support for delete query.

Anybody knows how to solve it instead of using a client?

The version of **spring-data-elasticsearch** is 2.0.1

**Update 03.05.2017**

First of all, in my code was an error with my deletion, don't how it worked before, but it should be:

```
  client.prepareDelete().setIndex("userindex")
    .setType("address")
    .setParent("500")
    .setId(id.toString())
  .execute().get();
```

Here **500** is parent id instead of type name.
And now about the *spring-data* way. There is no spring-data way in elasticsearch integration.

Proof:

[DATAES-257](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-257)

[DATAES-331](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-331)

Answer (score -4):

If you want to do it the Spring way, you can use ***ElasticsearchTemplate*** which is much similar to RestTemplate.
ElasticsearchTemplate has **deleteIndex**() function which can delete the whole index. Also, you can do lots of other stuff with the template. 
Example project with delete index is here: https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-data-elastic-example-4/blob/master/src/main/java/com/techprimers/elastic/resource/SearchResource.java

Code:

```
@Autowired
ElasticsearchTemplate template; 

template.deleteIndex(Users.class);
```

Comment: Ok, ugliest solution ever. Should I delete 2Gb index and recreate it every time when I need to delete one record?

Comment: cannot even be considered as solution

Comment: See merge request being done: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/562